# how to call a controller method in asp.net mvc and show the details in labels in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with a text box, when I type and enter a service number then it should retrieve the data from the database and show those in labels in the same view, This application is ASP.net MVC application. Can some one tell me how to do this. Thanks

Further more 
can I call controller methods without javascript

Is that possible to call controller methods in view and show the results in the same view
If can the show me how to do it, Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please read through the Help Center on asking a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. In particular, read "How do I ask a good question?"

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX. Let's have an example:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.FooBar, htmlAttributes: new { id = "fooBarLabel" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FooBar, new { id = "fooBar", data_url = Url.Action("CalculateValue") })
```

and then in a separate javascript file you could subscribe to the `.change` event of the text field and trigger an AJAX call to the controller action:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fooBar').change(function() {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#fooBarLabel').load(url, { value: value });
    });
});
```

and all that's left is the corresponding controller action:

```
public ActionResult CalculateValue(string value)
{
    // The value parameter will contain the text entered by the user in the text field
    // here you could calculate the value to be shown in the label based on it:

    return Content(string.Format("You entered: {0}", value));
}
```